# How to sum a field grouped by another in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find a away to SUM all the QUANTITY for a specific RECIPE (all its ingredients) into a single value to get the TOTAL QUANTITY

Assuming I have the following dataset:

```
RecipeName IngredientName ReceiptWeight
Food1      Ingredient1    5
Food1      Ingredient2    2
Food2      Ingredient1    12
Food2      Ingredient3    1
```

And I would expect to get the following:

```
RecipeName ReceiptWeight
Food1      7
Food2      13
```

The code I have so far is:

```
            Grouping =
                (
                from data in dataset
                group data by data.RecipeName into recipeGroup
                let fullIngredientGroups = recipeGroup.GroupBy(x => x.IngredientName)
                select new ViewFullRecipe()
                {
                    RecipeName = recipeGroup.Key,
                    ReceiptWeight = ????
```

How can I get the value for RecipeWeight?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ does have sum

```
from d in dataset
group d by new { d.RecipeName } into g
select new {
     g.Key.RecipeName,
     ReceiptWeight = g.sum(o => o.ReceiptWeight)
}
```